# Docker Build Using gcloud Configuration

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, dockerfile, gcloud

I have a use case where I would like to use a gcloud user configuration while building a docker image.

What is the best way to implement this configuration during the docker image build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build a Docker image either by using a *build config file* or a *Dockerfile*. First login to Google Cloud using `gcloud auth login` in the Cloud Shell command line. Then configure the project for gcloud using `gcloud config set project [PROJECT_ID]`, where "[PROJECT_ID]" is the GCP project ID you wish to use.

When using a build config file it instructs Cloud Build to perform tasks based on the specifications you provide in your *cloudbuild.yaml* file:

```
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: [ 'build', '-t', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/quickstart-image', '.' ]
images:
- 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/quickstart-image'
```

At build time, Cloud Build automatically replaces "$PROJECT_ID" with your project ID. You start the build by running this command:

```
gcloud builds submit --config cloudbuild.yaml
```

Use this [quickstart to get you started](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/quickstart-docker#build_using_a_build_config_file), and this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/build-config) to understand the structure of the configuration file for Google Cloud Build. Hope this helps!